# How to get GraphQL syntax features in my .js file on VSCode?

Tags: javascript, graphql, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded the GraphQL extension for VSCode but I know out of the box it only works for .graphql, .gql files. How can I get the syntax features to work in my .js files?